# Fabric plugin not integrated in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-fabric

I tried to integrate crashlytics using fabric plugin for distribute builds with different devices.

After integrated, Plugin show me to build and run your application but nothing happen after running application many times. its still showing same message.

Below is message:

[image]

Comment: What message you see?

Comment: Also check if Fabric could make change inside your app level `build.gradle` or not?

Comment: what message you are getting?

Comment: @Khemraj No, its not changing inside any file.

Comment: @Riser Which files you are talking about?

Comment: There is no message display.. just simple showing message in plugin..

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari i added screenshot

Comment: It make changes inside `build.gradle` file, if it is not able to make changes. Try restarting android studio, and reinstalling fabric plugin.

Comment: If plugin does not work afterward. Make changes yourself because that are only at most 5 lines.

Comment: @Khemraj i did all the things. still not working.

Comment: It can be some plugin error. My suggestion, don't waste time, Just add few lines yourself from official doc. https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html

Comment: @Khemraj i already add manually but still not working.. my application still not shoowing in fabric site.

Comment: @Riser you will get your all the error logs in your Crashlytics fabric account, which you used while integrating Fabric.

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari i am integrated for distribute application builds.

Comment: @Riser as per khemraj suggested the solution, did you try like that

Comment: Hi, Paul from Fabric here. To activate a new app in our system, the app must be built and run in the same time period (≈ one day). The combination of these events alerts our server that we need to register a new bundle ID.

Typically, when this error is shown, 1. you are building your app behind a proxy/firewall, so one or both of these events can't be sent, 2. the code changes were not properly done, 3. your app was not built or run.

Comment: @buser i already add code manually in my application and the built and run several times but still its not showing my application in fabric.

Comment: @Riser in that case I would recommend reaching out to us via email: support(at)fabric(dot)io

Answer (score 1):

Your app is not listed in Fabric Panel by just integrating Fabric in Android Project. You should run that in device and wait for sometime.

> Still if you can not see your app at Fabric Panel, You can make a fake/test crash.

You can make forceful crash by

- divide by zero
- get some item from empty list
- calling `this.stackOverflow();`
- `throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");`

Comment: In my case all that was needed is opening the app with Crashlytics installed, load the main screen and wait until the stats about the opened app will be processed.